# nested content_tags only showing the last of the chilldren rails view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am trying to do a little reusable helper to insert into a page of some descriptions with the content tag

```
def spec_description(name, overview, detail)
  content_tag :dl do
    content_tag :dt do
      content_tag(:strong, name)
    end
    content_tag :dd, overview, :class => "spec-overview"
    content_tag :dd, detail,   :class => "spec-detail" #only this dd tag gets output
  end
end
```

But as it is, only the dd tag with what is to be 'detail' gets output to the html

UPDATED
output html is like this now:

```
<dl>
   <dd>some detail from detail variable</dd>
</dl>
```

See how the "overview" and "name" dd tags are completely missing? Let alone their content...

Does anyone have an idea why this is and how I may fix it?

Comment: No actually, the dl came out, the dt isn't even there. and the first dd, the overview one, isn't there either. bizzare..I updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your helper is returning some HTML and its return value is whatever `content_tag :dl` returns.  The content of the `<dl>` will be whatever its block returns and the block returns the last value (i.e. the last `<dd>`). So you just have a return value problem:

```
def spec_description(name, overview, detail)
  content_tag :dl do
    html  = content_tag :dt { content_tag(:strong, name) }
    html += content_tag :dd, overview, :class => "spec-overview"
    html += content_tag :dd, detail,   :class => "spec-detail"
    html
  end
end
```

Comment: you're a saint. That explains it quite well. Not much was said about the return value of the content_tag block behaving this way. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nik: `content_tag` is usually used inside an ERB `<%= ... %>` or the block form where there's just HTML in the block so the return value handling is sort of hidden from you. I should have spotted the problem right away rather than on the second look.